# how to add text and image over the 360 images A-Frame

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, 360-virtual-reality

I wanna add text and image over the 360 image in  A-Frame how to add text and images above 360  ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
<!-- A-Frame standard library if needed -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/latest/aframe.js"></script>
<!-- Component (includes A-Frame core) -->
<script src="dist/aframe-no-click-look-controls.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
    <a-entity camera no-click-look-controls></a-entity>
            <h1>hello</h1>
    <a-sky src="https://cdn.glitch.com/fbc36a5e-0d0e-45d3-b6cb-
   0c1f01f6cd8e%2FMuttukadu%20Boat%20House(2K).jpg?1491283410006" 
  rotation="0 -130 0"></a-sky>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap `a-scene` in a `div` and set `position:relative` on it. Next, append another `div` to the contents of the first one (after `a-scene`) and set `position:absolute` on it. This will overlay the contents of the second `div` over the `a-scene`. Next, all you need to do is position the second `div` as required and add text and images inside of it. Should the second `div` contents not show, consider adjusting it's `z-index` value.

The resulting code would look something like this:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
    <a-scene>
        <!-- a-scene content here -->
    </a-scene>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:1000;">
        <!-- your overlay content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How about if we need the overlay content to be kind of mapped to a specific part of the <a-sky>? For example, I have a scene with a beach and a single house. I would like to overlay a button on top of the house. As we move the panorama around, the button would always be on top of the house.